# Object losing its prototype functions when I pass it to socket io

Tags: javascript, socket.io, agora.io

I am using Agora.io sdk to create a group video chat application. They provide developers with a stream object that is all encompassing of the important methods and properties required to build the app. However, when I pass it to socket io it loses its functions. How can I solve this problem. I saw some questions that ask similar questions but they don't provide an answer that has been able to help me.
Below is my code where I emit :

```
function UIControls (stream, streamType, streamDiv) {
    console.log('inside UIControls :::', stream.streamId, stream.getId(), typeof(stream) === 'function')

    // video button
    var videoButton = document.createElement('button');
    // videoButton.setAttribute('id', 'videoButton');
    videoButton.setAttribute('id', 'video_'+String(stream.getId()));
    videoButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-video"></i>';
    var clicked = false;
    videoButton.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
        toggleVideo(stream);
    })
    if (streamType === 'me') {
        $('#me').append(videoButton);
    } else {
        $('#' + String(stream.getId())).append(videoButton);
    } 

    function toggleVideo(stream) {
        if (clicked) {
            videoButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-video-slash"></i>';
            socket.emit("sendPeerInfo_video", {
                "type": "mute",
                "id": String(stream.getId()),
            });
            clicked = false;
        } else {
            // stream.unmuteVideo();
            videoButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-video"></i>';
            socket.emit("sendPeerInfo_video", {
                "type": "unmute",
                "id": String(stream.getId()),
                "stream": stream,
            });
            clicked = true;
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the socket.on code:

```
socket.on("sendPeerInfo_video", function (evt) {
    if (evt.type === 'mute') {
        evt.stream.muteVideo();
        return $('#video_'+evt.id)[0].innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-video-slash"></i>'
    } else if (evt.type === 'unmute') {
        evt.stream.unmuteVideo();
        return $('#video_'+evt.id)[0].innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-video"></i>'
    }
});
```

I don't have access to evt.stream.muteVideo() and evt.stream.unmuteVideo() functions anymore inside socket.on

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason why you are using your own sockets?

Check out this [sample app](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/group-video-chat) which takes care of group video calls and screen sharing along with features like muting and unmuting made using the official [Agora.io Documentation](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web/index.html).

A snippet showing what you actually need to do for what features you have given an example of:

```js
var client = AgoraRTC.createClient({mode: 'rtc', codec: 'vp8'}); 
var localStreams = {
  uid: '',
  camera: {
    camId: '',
    micId: '',
    stream: {}
  }
};

// Hide video
client.on("mute-video", function (evt) {
  var remoteId = evt.uid;
   localStreams.camera.stream.muteVideo();
});

// Show video
client.on("unmute-video", function (evt) {
 localStreams.camera.stream.unmuteVideo();
});

// Mute audio
client.on("mute-audio", function (evt) {
  var remoteId = evt.uid;
   localStreams.camera.stream.muteAudio();
});

// Unmute audio
client.on("unmute-audio", function (evt) {
 localStreams.camera.stream.unmuteAudio();
});
```

Agora automatically mutes and unmutes audio and video for everyone without you having to make your own socket for the same.

If your use case is something different though which needs you to use custom sockets, let me know in the comments.

**EDIT:**
To implement a hand raise feature as well as to mute or unmute someone else, you can use [Agora RTM](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_web/index.html) using this [quick start guide](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_web?platform=Web) or this [sample app](https://github.com/akshatvg/Agora-RTM-Web).

What RTM does is act like your personal web socket and can be used to send messages which are displayed to other users (for chatting) or even do some behind the scenes work like receiving a message of a particular type and performing an action accordingly.

If the admin wants to mute someone else, they can click on a button which triggers a RTM message to a user and automatically parse and use this message to mute him/her.
Hand raise will work in a similar way.

Comment: yes my case is a little different. Agora allows a local stream to mute or unmute their audio and video. A remote user cannot mute and unmute someones audio and video. I also wanted to implement a hand raise feature - on clicking the hand button, it displays a push notification in remote streams local window. So I used my own websockets to implement that functionality. Thanks for looking into this for me!

Comment: @JagnoorGrewal I have edited my answer to help solve your problem now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just looked into this and it's what I was looking for before I moved to websockets. Will definitely implement this